# Computing $\frac{(16!)!}{16!}$

Tags: factorial

I am having problems with this one. Can someone help me?

\begin{align}
\frac{(16!)!}{16!}
\end{align}

Comment: It will have all integer factors greater than $16$ and less than equal to $16!$. Basically it is $(16!-1)!$

Comment: Have u tried anything?

Comment: Are you looking for the value of this small number ?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $\displaystyle \frac{x!}{x}=(x-1)!$

Therefore, we have $\displaystyle \frac{(16!)!}{16!}=(16!-1)!$

Comment: I think you should put a bracket after first factorial sign as double factorial has different meaning as for example $4!!=4×2=8$ while $(4!)!=24!$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar is there a triple factorial, like 9!!! = 3 x 6 x 9??

Comment: No dont think so. Maybe you can see wolframalpha.

Comment: $9!!=9×7×5×3×1$

Comment: so like n !!!!!(a)!!!! = n(n-a)(n-2a)...etc while still being greater than 1

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=16!$.   What is $n!/n$?